# Heroku, GeoIP, Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, geolocation, geoip, amazon-route53

i was starting to setup 2-Region for my Heroku App, then create distribute the workload with Amazon Route 53 GeoDNS service.

Solution 1 fail

```
a = api.mydomain.com, Europe, myApp-EU.herokuapp.com
b = api.mydomain.com, US, myApp-US.herokuapp.com
```

a,b fail:
since Heroku don't know "api.mydomain.com".

Solution 2 fail

```
a = api.mydomain.com, Europe, CNAME api-eu.mydomain.com
b =  api.mydomain.com, US, CNAME api-us.mydomain.com
c =  api-eu.mydomain.com, Europe, myApp-EU.herokuapp.com
d =  api-us.mydomain.com, US, myApp-US.herokuapp.com
```

c,d work since heroku know "api-eu.mydomain.com".
a,b doesn't work since heroku don't know "api.mydomain.com"

At this point i would conclude that is not possibile with Herou?

Answer (score 0):

In an http/s environment, two factors have to come together.  (It is apparent from the question that you understand these two issues, but please indulge me while I clarify).

- The request hostname must be resolvable to an endpoint IP address, either directly, with a DNS `A` record, or indirectly, through `CNAME` records, *and*
- The destination must be expecting requests with the *original* hostname in the `Host:` http header.

Heroku evidently understands the concept that an app should support a custom hostname, e.g.,  `eu-app.example.com` or `api.example.com`.

If their system allowed you to assign the same host/domain name to both apps, the issue solves itself, because you'd configure the geographic DNS maps to the appropriate regional `CNAME` targets and it would work as expected.  Since you have asked this question, I assume this is not the case.

Depending on how useful it is to you to host on Heroku, given this apparent issue, a simple and relatively low cost solution would be an EC2 instance in each destination region, whose sole purpose is to receive those geographically routed requests, rewrite the `Host:` header to what Heroku expects to see, and reverse proxy the request.

I have a similar application where I have a static site with one hostname, stores in an S3 bucket with a different name.  For static web site hosting, S3 *requires* that the bucket name equal the value sent in the `Host:` header by the browser, which prevents a CNAME from a different hostname from working, for exactly the same reason that you are seeing here.

The proxy server runs HAProxy on a t2.micro instance, < $10/month, and serves many thousands of hits each day, barely using any CPU on the t2.micro (my credit balance is always over 100), since HAProxy is very well written and lean on resource usage.  Since the EC2 machine is in the same region as the S3 bucket, the additional latency added to each request is insignificant.  As an additional bonus, of course, I get real-time logging, header capture, and and external perspective on the performance and behavior of the back-end service.  Nginx or Varnish or several other proxy servers could probably be used for the same purpose.  You would put these in the same regions where your application is deployed, though for one region, you could skip it if the Heroku platform was expecting your `api.example.com` directly.  You'd technically only need this in one location.

The reason this works is that HAProxy doesn't care what the incoming `Host:` header contains, unless you configure it to make routing decisions based on that header.

You can also load your `api.example.com` SSL certificate on all of your HAProxy instances, and it will terminate the SSL and forward the request using a new SSL connection to the endpoint, which can be using any valid SSL cert, including any wildcard/non-vanity cert the destination endpoint may support.

Answer (score 0):

After some looking over different solutions i figure out how to handle it.
AKAMAI and Fastly are the 2 CDN service that allow you to override the 'http host header'. In this way Heroku know that the request came from "api-eu.mydomain.com" since Akamai was able to ovverride the "api.mydomain.com" host-header.